# App.config validation

Tags: c#, .net, validation, config

Good day. I think all .Net Web developers are faced with the problem of incorrect config files. 
Sometimes it has no connection strings or settings or endpoint.

Is there a good practice to validate and show detailed message (for example "Endpoint is not available")?

Such validation is better than handle a `NullReferenceException` in some places of code. It will give understanding of the reason of the problem. And deploy team will can solve this problems themselves

For example, I want to check next things:
1. Some values in AppSettings are can correctly parsed (parsed as int or as datetime)
2. All connections strings are correct and application can connect to it
3. All endpoints are available
4. Some more specific things like: If current build configuration is STG, then all endpoints should starts from STG etc.

Comment: It's unclear what you are actually asking for. Where would you want to add this "validation" and how would it work?

Comment: You can read the xml file using `xmldocument` or `xelement` in C# and check specific `element / attribute` if exist and if its value meet the condition you give

Comment: No. xmldocument  is a bicycle. I want to create some Rules like:
1. App settings should contains list of requered settings, or
2. Endpoint-URL should refference to production in prod mode and to staging in stg mode
3. ConnectionStrings should be correct
4. etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example for connectionString, you have to create a bool function who returns kind of sql exception failed connection before writing message according with that. This is a step you have to follow :

1) Create a bool function **(for example named CheckConnection())** to check connectionString (use **try catch** block and push Exception types you want there)

2) After proceed to an if statement when you write your message :
ex :

```
if (CheckConnection())
{
    Console.WriteLine("Database connection success");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Failed to connect to the database");
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but It seems like a bicycle. I want to found some variety of Good Practise.